# How to goBack when there's "no html tag" I want to get, in RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium-chromedriver

I'm scraping some community posts by RSelenium.

Using clickElement() to go into the article url, and use goBack() to return to the first screen.

But I have a problem when going into the specific article, which is removed.

On the first screen, there's an article in the list, but when I clickElement() that specific article, it shows me "The article is removed" and then redirect to other url.

So I get error and it stop works.

This is my code.

```
 for(i in 1:25){
    tryCatch({
      title_url <- mybrowser$findElement('xpath', paste0('//*[@id="container"]/div/section[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[',i,']/a'))
      title_url$clickElement()
      Sys.sleep(sample(1:3,1))
      html <- mybrowser$getPageSource()[[1]]
      post_html <- read_html(html)
      title <- post_html %>% html_node('.title_subject') %>% html_text('span')
      datetime <- post_html %>% html_node('.gall_date') %>% html_text()
      content <- post_html %>% html_node(xpath='//*[@id="container"]/section/article[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]') %>% html_text()
      mybrowser$goBack()
      })
  }
```

I'm expecting to use goBack() function whatever error you have.

Error like

1. if there's no html tag I expected.
2. redirect to other url which I haven't expected.

etc.

Please help me :(